# Django Crispy Form With Dynamically Defined Field

Tags: django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I would like to define a Django crispy form with two statically defined fields (`name` and `description`) and one dynamically defined field (`enum_value`). I do it like this:

```
class DataTypeForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.mode = kwargs.pop('mode')
        super(DataTypeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.wrapper_class = 'row'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-8'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
        self.fields['enum_value'] = forms.CharField()
```

The dynanic field `enum_value` is defined in the last line. Unfortunately, this does not work as expected: the form is rendered with the two static fields (`name` and `description`) but the dynamic field `enum_value` is not visible. The problem seems to  lie in the use of the `FormHelper` class. If I modify my example as follows:

```
class DataTypeForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.mode = kwargs.pop('mode')
        super(DataTypeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
#        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
#        self.helper.wrapper_class = 'row'
#        self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-2'
#        self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-8'
#        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
        self.fields['enum_value'] = forms.CharField()
```

then, things work as expected and all three fields in my form are correctly rendered. Is there any way I can get the dynamically defined field correctly rendered even when using the `FormHelper` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placing the dynamic field `enum_value` before the creation of the `FormHelper` should work.

```py
class DataTypeForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.mode = kwargs.pop('mode')
        super(DataTypeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['enum_value'] = forms.CharField()
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.wrapper_class = 'row'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-8'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
```

Comment: Yes, I confirm that the proposed solution works! Many thanks.